# Why am I not getting the correct distance between two corelocation's?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to calculate distance between two corelocation objects like this:

```
float meters = [destinationLocation distanceFromLocation:currentLocationNew];
distanceBtwTwoLocations = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f miles",meters];
```

But it is not giving me the exact distance. Why ? I just checked the values in console

currentLocationNew <+17.42369091, +78.43235230> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/06/11 12:43:59 PM India Standard Time

destinationLocation <+16.29850960, +80.43364716> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/06/11 12:44:07 PM India Standard Time

distanceBtwTwoLocations 247043 miles

Am I missing anything??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

247,043 *miles* is about the distance to the moon and there are no two points on the planet that far apart unless you're going the whole way round, ten times over (the circumference is only about 25,000 miles).

I'm pretty certain that your problem lies with the units you're choosing to display, especially since the variable name you're using is `meters` rather than `miles`. 247,000 *metres* is only about 250kms, a couple of hours in a fast car, and matches your lat/long values, at least roughly.

Your value of 247,043 has to be [converted from meters to miles](http://www.metric-conversions.org/length/meters-to-miles.htm) (1 mile is about 1609.344 meters) and dividing it by that gives you what you're expecting, 153.5 miles.

Comment: No, I am giving the exact lat and lon values to 2 corelocation objects .. even though I am not getting the exact distance.

Comment: @Dee, what _is_ the correct distance you think it should be. Which cities are represented by those co-ordinates?

Comment: It's about 153 miles distance from Hyderabad to Guntur, It's showing as 247,043 miles.

Comment: Google says it's 276km on the roads so straight line distance will be around 250km. In meters the calculation is probably correct http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=FUvdCQEdYMisBA%3BFQ6y-AAd71HLBA&q=%2B17.42369091,+%2B78.43235230+to+%2B16.29850960,+%2B80.43364716&aq=&sll=17.420221,78.429594&sspn=0.027967,0.045447&ie=UTF8&z=9&saddr=%2B17.42369091,+%2B78.43235230&daddr=%2B16.29850960,+%2B80.43364716

Comment: @Dee, you need to re-read my answer. _Your_ code is stating that it's 247,043 miles but that's because you're using the wrong units. 247,043 _meters_ is 153.5 miles.

Answer (score 1):

What have you calculated as the correct distance yourself?

The distance is given in meters according to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW18)

If you need to use miles you just have to convert meters to miles.